# Qt C++ Slowly move QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have QListWidget which I need to move from one point to another but it has to be slow, something like animation. Can you help me with this.

Comment: Have you read about Qt Animation framework already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Qt Animation framework](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/animation-overview.html) for this. There are many samples available, so you should read it.

What you are trying to do can be done with [QPropertyAnimation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qpropertyanimation.html) class, by animating [geometry](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) property of `QListWidget`:

```
 QPropertyAnimation animation(&lstWidget, "geometry"); //animate geometry property
 animation.setDuration(5000); // 5 seconds 
 animation.setStartValue(QRect(50, 50, 100, 100)); // start value for geometry property
 animation.setEndValue(QRect(300, 300, 100, 100)); // end value for geometry property

 animation.start();
```

This will move from widget from (50,50) to (300, 300). You can set start value by reading `geometry` property from `lstWidget` to start moving from the current position, etc.

Comment: I've tried that, but it's not animating, it just jumps to new location. I need to run those lines of code when button is pressed. All is done using Qt Designer.

Comment: @Alen make sure animation object is not deleted when you exit the function. Try to allocate animation on a heap (`QPropertyAnimation * animation = new QPropertyAn...`) and call `animation->start()`, or move `animation` to be your class member, as you will use it again and again.